# Why isn't my Preferences DataStore value being set?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, androidx, android-jetpack-datastore

My understanding of AndroidX DataStore is the operations are supposed to be thread-safe and transactional. But I'm setting a value then immediately reading it, and the value has not been updated. What am I doing wrong? This shouldn't be possible should it?

Here are my "get" and "set" functions.

```
fun getValue(keyStr: String): String
{
    val key = stringPreferencesKey(keyStr)
    val value = runBlocking {
        context.dataStore.data.map { it[key] ?: "" }
    }
    return runBlocking { value.first() }
}

fun setValue(keyStr: String, valueStr: String) {
    val key = stringPreferencesKey(keyStr)
    runBlocking {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences -> preferences[key] = valueStr }
    }
}
```

And here is how they call them in my Application's CREATE method.

```
    setValue("TEST", "testing")
    val test = getValue("TEST")
```

After the "get" call, test=="".

Comment: This code works fine for me, getValue returns "testing"